# On duplicate key query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

I'm trying to execute the following sql query on postgres:

```
INSERT INTO Works_On (ESSN,PNo,Hours) VALUES ('199112111',3,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Hours = 3;
```

But when I do I get an error which follows:

```
psql:test2.sql:2: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 2: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Hours = 3;
        ^
```

I can't really find the error, help would be most appreciated!

Comment: You are using MySQL syntax on Postgres.  That is why you are getting the error.

Comment: with `psql` it's looks like you are using postgresql. Added the same tag. Moreover there is no `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in postgresql. See this related post which may be of your help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is not available in postgresql. You can run the following query.

```
UPDATE Works_on SET Hours = 3 WHERE ESSN='199112111' AND PNo=3;
INSERT INTO table (id, field, field2)
       SELECT '199112111',3,3
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Works_on WHERE ESSN='199112111' AND PNo=3);
```

Here , `UPDATE` query will succeed if there is already a row with `ESSN='199112111' AND PNo=3`

`INSERT` query will succeed if row with `ESSN='199112111' AND PNo=3` does not exist.